# Calculated field returning #Type error

Tags: database, ms-access

**Small pizzas cost £6.00** and all **toppings are £1.50**. I have created a **calculated field** that should **add up** the cost of the small pizza and the topping to get the **total amount**. This is returning the value **#Type!** even after changing the result type of the calculated field.

I am trying to **add up** the values within the textbox (which uses the 'Lookup' data type to store the values within a drop down box) to calculate a total cost for the order.

Any solutions?

[Calculated field expression and result type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unvz8.png)

[Order form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz0in.png)

Comment: At what point of the form load is the *Lookup* field populated? When is the *calculated field* calculated? is the calculation done **after** *Lookup* population?

Comment: @marlan The lookup field is already populated with the pizza sizes and cost. The calculated field is calculated when the user has selected a value from both text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculated field `Result Type` must be `Currency`, not `Integer.`

This assumes that both your `Pizza Size` and `Toppings` fields are Currency too.

Note that calculated fields in tables are generally viewed as a bad idea, see e.g. here:
[Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Comment: Thanks, Ill try that